# Generator returning same value

Tags: python, generator

So I have this code:

```
def odds():
    number = 1

    while True:
        yield number
        number += 2

nums = odds()

for _ in range(100):
    print(next(nums))
```

and this one:

```
def odds():
    number = 1

    while True:
        yield number
        number += 2

for _ in range(100):
    print(next(odds()))
```

The first part, when run, returns `1, 3, 5 ...`, but the second one: `1, 1, 1, 1...`, just 1's. Why is that?
Note that the difference is that , in the second part, I didn't type `nums = odds()`.

Comment: In the 2nd one you're re-building the generator each iteration of the loop

Comment: Oh! I get it! Thanks!